# Google Analytics link to Adwords

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

Having trouble linking separate accounts from GA to Adwords.  They are different emails, both tracking the same site.  The main GA email works with a lot of different sites, so I don't want the Adwords to have access to all of it. 
The Adwords account seems to have created its own analytics site --but it's not the one I've been working with.
Help?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the possible solution to your problem is setting the cross-account conversion tracking by creating the My Client Center (MCC) account: https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1704399?rd=1

This account is actually an AdWords account that lets you easily view and manage all of your AdWords accounts (including other MCC manager accounts) from a single location.

For additional information, please refer to:

https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/3030657?hl=en

http://www.wordstream.com/blog/ws/2013/08/06/link-adwords-to-analytics-guide

Hope I helped.